# Is it possible to use rooted glob patterns in .hgignore?

Tags: mercurial, hgignore

I prefer to use glob syntax in my .hgignore files, but now I need to create a rooted pattern.  I want to ignore my /static directory, but not /assets/static.  The line

```
static/
```

ignores both.  Is there a way to do rooted glob patterns?  If not, I can switch to regex, but glob just seems so much more natural for matching pathnames.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot root your glob patterns — this is documented in [the manpage](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgignore.5.html). You can, however, switch back and forth between the glob and regexp syntax:

```
syntax: glob
*.pyc

syntax: regexp
^static/

syntax: glob
*~
```

Answer (score 5):

According to [*hgignore* (5)](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgignore.5.html), it's not possible with globs:

> Neither glob nor regexp patterns are rooted. A glob-syntax pattern of the form *.c will match a file ending in .c in any directory, and a regexp pattern of the form .c$ will do the same. To root a regexp pattern, start it with ^.