# How to ignore folder in mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I have following project strucure:

`projectA 
   build/
 projectB
   build/
build`

I would like to ignore everything which is under build folder.
I used following in the .hgignore file:

```
syntax: glob
build/**
```

It ignores build folder under projectA and projectB, but it doesn't ignore build folder in the root.
How can I accomplish the build folder in the root to also be ignored?

Best regards,
mismas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The glob syntax in Mercurial does not operate from the root folder, as you've found it'll match the path wherever in the tree it occurs.
To match relative to the root you'll need to use the regexp syntax, so try:

```
syntax: regexp
^build/
```

or

```
syntax: regexp
^build$
```

And you can have both regexp and glob syntax in your hgignore file, you just lay it out as follows:

```
syntax: glob
*.pyc

syntax: regexp
^static/

syntax: glob
*~
```

Originally from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673783/is-it-possible-to-use-rooted-glob-patterns-in-hgignore)

Comment: Thank you for reply :) I have tried syntax: regexp
^build/ , but it didn't help

Comment: Also it is wiered to me that after right click project > Team > Synchronize the build folder in the root is recognized as D:build and not as d:\workspaces\workspace1\build.

Comment: build folder is in the root of the project, same as .hgignore file

Comment: When you say it didn't help, is it matching nothing now, or still matching the subfolders as well? What client are you using to do this? Do you see the same behaviour if you use the command line?

Comment: It is matching nothing now. I am using eclipse hg plugin which points to mercurial executable C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\hg.exe (version 2.4.2). I also tried hg status from command line and it matches nothing. All build directories are present ...

Comment: Do you have more suggestions how to resolve this problem? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: And just for absolute clarity, exactly what does your ignore file contain now?

Comment: ProjectA/dist
.*\.log
.*\.class
syntax: regexp
^build/

Comment: if I add 'syntax: glob
build/** ' to it, then build folders are ignored, except the root one (which I would like to ignore also)

Comment: Has anything in the build folder been committed previously?

Comment: First items regarding .log nad .class files are still working. No, didn't commit anything from the build folder.

Comment: How about removing the slash at the end of it and seeing if that works first and if not then try replacing the slash with a $ symbol as per   http://mercurial.808500.n3.nabble.com/Example-hgignore-regarding-whole-directories-td794536.html

Comment: I'm sorry I'm all out of ideas, those should work. I'm using Mercurial 2.7.1 and it works fine with it.

Answer (score 0):

Are the not files already added in that folder? Then you need to run hg forget on those files. Changes afterwards on .hgignore are only applied for newly  added files!

Answer (score 0):

This is how my file looks like in the end:

```
ProjectA/dist
.*\.log
.*\.class
build/
^\.gradle/
^\.settings
```

I needed to restart Eclipse in order for this to work.
@Nanhydrin thanks for your help :)